# Can't launch ubuntu on chromebook after restarting

Tags: xubuntu, chromebook

I have an asus c300 chromebook and I recently installed ubuntu on it. The installation worked fine and I had ubuntu on my chromebook for a while. I then restarted the chromebook. I then tried to launch the Chromebook back into Ubuntu with the command:

```
sudo startxfce4
```

I got the following:

```
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.10.18 #1 SMP Mon Nov 30 22:26:59 PST 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=19b58f0d-a082-5546-bf06-a419143d6f25/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=19b58f0d-a082-5546-bf06-a419143d6f25/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=a22384fe4ab9d567d952e56dc3c566df35b155d8 salt=9c29906b67e0c7a513ed90e178e21f753eeb8710d8261b29870eda5506e1004f" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=19b58f0d-a082-5546-bf06-a419143d6f25 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:01PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Mon Dec  7 17:46:04 2015
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at (can't post link bc i dont have reputation of 10)
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "(can't post the site because I don't have a reputation of 10)" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I already tried reinstalling ubuntu but after reinstalling, every time I restart the chromebook, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the Crosh in chrome, Then type in

> shell

After typing that in type in

> sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -n precise -u

Then you may start up the environment by typing in

> Sudo startunity